# Постановка знаков препинания при обобщающем слове

Tags: пунктуация, тире, смысл

9. Если обобщающее слово в целях усиления его смысловой роли при большом числе однородных членов предложения употреблено дважды — перед перечислением и после него, то сохраняется принятая для конструкций с однородными членами и обобщающим словом пунктуация, т. е. двоеточие перед однородными членами и тире после них.

   Вместо двоеточия перед однородными членами в этих случаях возможно тире (т. е. однородные члены с двух сторон выделяются тире. ([Д. Э. Розенталь](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103))

**Все это /1 - звуки и запахи, тучи и люди /2 — было странно красиво и грустно /3 , казалось началом чудной сказки.**
[Максим Горький](https://books.google.ru/books?id=Xj7EySvpRRgC&pg=PA73&lpg=PA73&dq=%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20-%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B8,%20%D1%82%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B8%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE,%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8&source=bl&ots=2qDipBf5R5&sig=ACfU3U1r7QyT24lXppXEDjpsQjM-i8TZzg&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjbucTYk7_jAhUtwcQBHRgwCJgQ6AEwBXoECAgQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%92%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D1%8D%D1%82%D0%BE%20-%20%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%83%D0%BA%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%85%D0%B8%2C%20%D1%82%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BB%D1%8E%D0%B4%D0%B8%20%E2%80%94%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%83%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%8C%20%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BC%20%D1%87%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B9%20%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BA%D0%B8&f=true)

**Примечание**: это оригинальная версия постановки знаков препинания М.Г. (тире-тире), отличная от моей версии (двоеточие-тире).

/1 - перечисление, где "это" обобщающее слово. Поставил **двоеточие**;

/2 - БСП1, **это**-подлежащее, **было** сказуемое. Поставил **тире**: перечисление закончилось. Началось отношением **следовательно** (это было странно это было красиво и это было грустно);

/3 - БСП2, **это** подлежащее, **казалось** - сказуемое. Поставил **запятую**.

Если я ничего не путаю, то у предложения однородные соподчиненные придаточные.

**Вопрос**: как правильно определять, где акцент на обобщающем слове, а где просто перечисление через двоеточие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Все это: **звуки и запахи, тучи и люди** — было странно красиво и грустно, казалось началом чудной сказки.*

**Грамматический разбор:**

Предикативная основа (подлежащее + сказуемое): ***всё это //было красиво и грустно, казалось началом***.

Обобщающее слово — ***всё это***, оно является подлежащим, а сказуемое в этом предложении **составное именное**, осложненное однородными отношениями: *было, казалось;  было красиво и грустно.*

К обобщающему слову (подлежащему) относится обособленный однородный ряд, раскрывающий его содержание: ***звуки и запахи, тучи и люди.***

Таким образом, это **простое**  предложение, осложненное однородным рядом с обобщающим словом и однородными сказуемыми.  Оно является простым, так как в нем **только одна предикативная основа.**

Надо сказать, что для изучения обобщающих слов это предложение не лучший вариант (у него сложная грамматика).

**Пояснение**

1) **Обобщающее слово** (ОС) — это обычно местоимение или слово с неопределенным значение (всё, всегда, везде, эти люди и т.д), содержание которого раскрывает однородный ряд (всё, а именно что).

Надо обратить внимание на то, что ОС и однородные члены имеют **одинаковую грамматическую форму,** в данном случае это сущ. в И.п.

ОС стоит **в начале или в конце** однородного ряда.

По этим признакам вы можете определить наличие в предложении ОС.

2) **Знаки препинания**

**Обособление однородного ряда**: двоеточие после обобщающего слова и тире в конце ряда.

**Запятыми** (попарно) разделяются члены обособленного однородного ряда.

**Запятая** ставится между однородными сказуемыми (перечисление): было (), казалось ().

Примечание: Термин ***перечисление*** относится к любым однородным членам.  Здесь перечисляются (1) члены обособленного однородного ряда и (2) однородные сказуемые (*было, казалось*).

Comment: Sharon, простите, пожалуйста! Я процитировал собственный вариант. У Розенталя было упражнение "Прочитайте тексты и объясните постановку знаков препинания". Т.е, в (1) стояло тире, а не двоеточие (я исправил вопрос). Думаете, двоеточие возможно? Глубоко извиняюсь!

Comment: После обобщающего слова ставится двоеточие, но оно может заменяться тире. Оба варианта правильны.